# How to get notification on coming call on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

We need to develop an application for Windows Phone 7 and we need to know when a call is happening (to stop it).
Do we have this functionality in SDK?
Can we receive a notification when call is happening?

Best regards,
B

Comment: you won't be able to stop a call from coming in. that would make having a phone pretty pointless.

Comment: that would make your application pretty rude, no?

Comment: Is the "it" you are referring to ("to stop it") the phone call or the application you are writing?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7 App Certification requirements ([here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558)) clearly state that applications cannot interfere with normal workings of the phone functionality.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i'm aware this functionality is not available in the SDK and only available to OEM companies as allowing any developer access to this kind of information would be a security risk and lead to various bogus applications.

What do you need to stop, you certainly can't stop the incoming call.  Your application should handle incoming calls automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with everything that was said here up until this point. There is no managed API to stop a phone call, and based on the certification guidelines your app will not pass marketplace certification if you attempt to do so.

One thing I would add is that whenever there's a phone call, your App will be partially/completely obscured by the Phone UI. Which causes the [PhoneApplicationFrame.Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28VS.92%29.aspx) event to fire, so you can at least know when there's an incoming phone call. Though, the Obscured event fires for many other things (lock screen, text message, et al).

Comment: FYI: When incoming call is happening, cellular connection is dropped.