# Handling call events in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I just want to know whether has anyone tried to handle incoming calls through the application. Like, rejecting call if it matches a blacklist, answer, hold etc through the application.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045131/how-to-get-notification-on-coming-call-on-windows-phone-7). And from those answers I learn that is not possible to block/reject a phone call as this would interfere with the normal functionality of the phone. The [App Certification requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558) clearly state that this is not allowed. In short, even if you would succeed on doing this, your app wouldn't make it through validation to the MarketPlace.

Comment: Oh, then we wont be able to develop apps which can handle calls.. For example an answering machine...?

Comment: By my knowledge, an 'answering machine' is on the side of your carrier and not some sort of app on your device. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Ofcourse carrier side, but in a developing countries like India doesnt have those features yet on their carriers and app like answering machine is possible in Android, Symbian

Comment: Ok, but I certainly don't think it is possible on the WP7 platform. :)

Comment: Yes, i searched everywhere and is not possible in WP7. WP has many restrictions on developers.. :(

Comment: did u find any solution ? how about incoming call handler event in windows phone 8? do we get any event like 'Obscured' in windows phone 8?